# "Cannot convert from int[] to int" when using arrays with variables

Tags: java, arrays, int

I get an error on the lines:

```
int B = test3[y];
// and
int C = test3[z];
```

The error is:

> Cannot convert from int[] to int.

Here is my full code:

```
int[][] test3 = new int[3][3];

for(int y = 0; y < test3.length; y++){

    for(int z = 0; z < test3[0].length; z++){
        test3[y][z] = z;

        int B = test3[y];
        int C = test3[z];

        System.out.print(B + "/" + C);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to print?

Comment: What part of that precise error message do you not get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Fixing the error try to change those lines:

```
 for(int z = 0; z < test3[0].length; z++){
        test3[y][z] = z;

        int B = test3[y];
        int C = test3[z];

        System.out.print(B + "/" + C);
    }
```

With those lines:

```
for(int z = 0; z < test3[y].length; z++){
        test3[y][z] = z;

        int B = test3[y][z];
        int C = test3[z][y];

        System.out.println(B + "/" + C);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is obviously here:

```
    int B = test3[y];
    int C = test3[z];
```

You are trying to store an array of integers as an integer in both lines. `test3` is a 2-dimensional array and both `test3[y]` and `test3[z]` are 1-dimensional arrays, that is, the `y`'th or the `z`'th "row", respectively. You probably wanted to get some integer values, like the `z`'th column of the `y`'th row (`test3[y][z]`), or the `y`'th column of the `z`'th row (`test3[z][y]`). Without further information I cannot help you more.